# Camel count number of files got routed or consumed

Tags: java, apache-camel

I want to know number of files got transferred or you can say acknowledgement or notification after each file transferred from consumer to producer.

like simple example

```
from("file:in").
   .to("file:out");
```

I used .onCompetion() and also tried processor but not worked for me as i am a newbie. Code sample will be very helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use `CamelBatchSize` exchange property. This property gives back the total number of Exchanges that was polled in this batch:

```
from("file:in").
    .log("CamelBatchSize (header)   = ${header.CamelBatchSize}")
    .log("CamelBatchSize (property) = ${property.CamelBatchSize}")
    .to("file:out");
```

`CamelBatchSize` is supported by all Camel batch consumers, see [here](http://camel.apache.org/batch-consumer.html). Other properties supported are:

- `CamelBatchIndex`: The current index of the batch. Starts from 0.
- `CamelBatchComplete`: A boolean indicating the last Exchange in the batch. Is only true for the last entry.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I think it will not work if consumer is HDFS2, in that case what do you suggest?

Comment: @PeterKeller can I set this property?

Answer (score -1):

This is a really simple example of using the processor:

```
from("file:in").to("file:out")
    .process(new Processor() {
    private int count = 0;
    public void process(Exchange exchange)
    {
       count++;
       System.out.println("Count: " + count);
    }
});
```

If you just want to see an acknowledgement of the file having been written, you can just use a log statement:

```
from("file:in").to("file:out").log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Message transferred!");
```

Comment: @mdnghtblue It will count number of Exchanges, not the number of files. A big file will have many Exchanges. Am i right?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the relationship between a file and an Exchange is one-to-one. Every time a file is consumed from "file:in", the File component will create an exchange to represent that file as it passes it through the route.

Comment: @mdnghtblue No, i already tried that. Consumer consume big files in chunks.

Comment: How big are these files? How do you know they're being split into different exchanges? Splitting up the file into different exchanges  defeats the whole purpose of an exchange, which is Camel's way of defining separate messages.

Comment: yeah i apologies, you are right. It was my mistake i used HDFS2 for consumer and it is not a Batch Consumer, that's why its consuming files in chunks.

Answer (score -1):

You can maybe use a (static) variable that you increment in a processor or something else.

```
int counter=0;
from("file:in")
   .to("file:out")
   .process(new Processor() {

            @Override
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                counter++;
                //notification or something else
            }
   });
```

Comment: You can access only final variable inside Instance of another object. If you use counter as final then you cannot modify immutable Types in a another instance of object.

Comment: @HoneyGoyal You can write the counter into the exchange header.